# Passing namespace as variable to vuex-map-fields mapFields function

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm attempting to pass the namespace/module name to the mapFields function as a variable.  The reason is I have a form that acts as both a demographics capture form for a membership database, as well as the demographics form for a member's profile.  To prevent the "membership database" from overriding the "profile" I have two modules/namespaces within the store and I want to direct the mapFields function based on the usage of the component.

The parent passes a property to the form, and I use that property in the function call, but get an error: "TypeError:  Cannot read property 'mod' of undefined"

Here's what my code looks like:

In the parent component:

```
<demographics :mod="mod"></demographics>
...
export default {
   ...
   data() {
      return {
         mod: "database"
      }
   },
...
```

In my child component:

```
export default {
...
props: ['mod'],
computed: {
   ...mapFields(this.mod, [<<<FIELDS HERE>>>]),
}
...
```

if I replace "this.mod" with the explicit 'database' everything will work find.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

When mapFields is called, the context of `this` changes because of the way mapFields internals are designed. (e.g. [An internal arrow function](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields/blob/b7affaf261a9e00938d605ed20c05e7fa991f383/src/index.js#L8-L22) inherits the enclosing scope's `this` instead of your external `this`)

You'll need to establish a value that can preserve the reference to your `mod` value via your component's `this` context. How best to do this depends on your needs/preferences. There is [a quirky suggestion in a vuex-map-fields GitHub issue](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields/issues/24#issuecomment-489356408) that involves remapping `this` to a `self` variable during the `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook but it was reported to have certain limitations.

```
let self;
export default {
...
  props: ['mod'],
  computed: {
     ...mapFields(self.mod, [<<<FIELDS HERE>>>]),
  },
  beforeCreate() { self = this },
...
```

Alternatively, you could supply your `mod` value outside of the `this` context of the component such as importing a context-specific `mod` constant rather than passing it down as a prop through descendant components.

```
import { PARENT_CONTEXT_MOD } from '../../ParentContext/module/consts.js'

export default {
...
  props: ['mod'],
  computed: {
     ...mapFields(PARENT_CONTEXT_MOD, [<<<FIELDS HERE>>>]),
  }
...
```